# Error: no match for 'operator-' operand types are: string, int. Text display in cmd

Tags: c++

I am trying to display this code in cmd so that it would send a text using two functions. The text:
"9 bottles of beer on the wall, 99 bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around - 98 bottles of beer on the wall." However, it doesn't work and I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int globalx;
int resault;

int calculate(int globalx);

string display(){
    string s = to_string(resault);
    string text1=cout<<s<<" bottles of beer on the wall, "<<s<<" bottles of beer. Take one down and pass it around - "<<s-1<<" bottles of beer on the wall."<<endl; // This error is connectect to this line`

    return text1;
}

int calculate(int globalx){
    for(int i=99;i>0;i--){
        globalx-=1;
    }
    return resault=globalx;
}

int main(){
    cout<<display()<<calculate(99)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `s-1` supposed to be? Why do you convert the `int` to a `string` at all? Just stream it out directly.

Comment: Its diffrent error if I delete the conversion. error: conversion from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} requested|

Comment: You get a different error. You also try streaming to a string. It doesn't support that. You also try to call `text1` as if it was a function when it is in fact a local variable inside another function.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what that is so I have to google that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notable problems:

- `s` is a `string` and you try to subtract `1` from it. A `string` does not support that operation.
- You try to store the result of streaming to `cout` in a `string` (`string text1=cout<<s ...`). A `string` does not support that operation either.
- You use global variables for an unclear purpose. I can't figure out what you want with `return resault=globalx;`.
- You call `calculate(99)` but you disregard the argument inside the function and start looping from `99` no matter what argument the function got.

... there are probably more things. I suggest removing the global variables and call the functions with the information they need - and stream directly to `cout` at this stage.

A simplification of your program:

```
#include <iostream>

void wyswietl(int resault) {
    std::cout << resault << " bottles of beer on the wall, " << resault << " bottles of beer. "
        "Take one down and pass it around - " << (resault-1) <<" bottles of beer on the wall.\n";
}

void calculate(int x){
    for(int i = x; i > 0; i--) {
        wyswietl(i);
    }
}

int main(){
    calculate(99);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will take all the critique to heart and improve, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting indicates that, somewhere, you tried to subtract an `int` from a `std::string`, which isn't allowed in C++. (A good intuition for this: what should `"Hi mom!" - 137`be?)

This specifically happens right here:

```
... << s - 1 << ...
```

Think about what quantity you actually want to subtract one from here, then see if you can adjust the code to fix this.